# Make record specific TextBox Control grow vertically in form view

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

First, my English is not very good.
Do you know if there is a way to make grow vertically and specific record of a continuous form while keeping the rest of records from growing? For example on reports if I set a textBox "letGrow" property to true, if the text inside that control occupies various lines the control grows, but just on that specific record. I would like similar behavior on forms "normalView".

Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

That is not an option. CanGrow is for reports only.

You can adjust height on the fly, but that will touch all records displayed.